# Use TDictionary in C++ Builder XE2

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++builder, c++builder-xe2

Currently I want to use `TDitionary` in C++ Buillder XE2

After I read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary) I thought it should have been easy but I even can not create a `TDictionary` object...

My code:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include <Generics.collections.hpp>
#include "TDictionaryTest.h"

#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm2 *Form2;

void __fastcall TForm2::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    TDictionary__2 <String, String> *Dir = new  TDictionary__2<String, String>(0);
    delete Dir;
}
```

Error messages:

```
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall           System::Generics::Collections::TDictionary__2<System::UnicodeString,   System::UnicodeString>::~TDictionary__2<System::UnicodeString, System::UnicodeString>()'  referenced from ...\PRACTICE\C++\WIN32\DEBUG\TDICTIONARYTEST.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::Generics::Collections::TEnumerable__1<System::Generics::Collections::TPair__2<System::UnicodeString, System::UnicodeString> >::~TEnumerable__1<System::Generics::Collections::TPair__2<System::UnicodeString, System::UnicodeString> >()' referenced from ...\PRACTICE\C++\WIN32\DEBUG\TDICTIONARYTEST.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::Generics::Collections::TDictionary__2<System::UnicodeString, System::UnicodeString>::' referenced from ...\PRACTICE\C++\WIN32\DEBUG\TDICTIONARYTEST.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall System::Generics::Collections::TDictionary__2<System::UnicodeString, System::UnicodeString>::TDictionary__2<System::UnicodeString, System::UnicodeString>(int)' referenced from ...\PRACTICE\C++\WIN32\DEBUG\TDICTIONARYTEST.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
```

Anyone has any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like @mhtaqia said, C++ cannot instantiate Delphi's Generics classes yet, only consume them when they are created by Delphi code.  For C++ code, you should use an STL `std::map` instead:

```
#include <map> 

void __fastcall TForm2::FormCreate(TObject *Sender) 
{ 
    std::map<String, String> *Dir = new std::map<String, String>; 
    delete Dir; 
}
```

Or:

```
#include <map> 

void __fastcall TForm2::FormCreate(TObject *Sender) 
{ 
    std::map<String, String> Dir; 
}
```

On a side note: **DO NOT** ever use the `TForm::OnCreate` and `TForm::OnDestroy` events in C++.  They are Delphi idioms that can produce illegal behavior in C++ as they can be triggered before your derived constructor and after your derived destructor, respectively.  Use the actual constructor/destructor instead.

Comment: @Remy OnCreate has nothing to do with the C++ constructor or the Delphi constructor. In a VCL application the class constructor is always called first. When VCL has created ALL the VCL components on a form the OnCreate Event handler is called. You should always use and initialize the form's VCL components here, not in the class constructor. The same goes for OnDestroy, called before the class destructor, when you still have access to all the VCL components. Then the class destructor is called. But you should not call OnCreate and OnDestroy on your own, maybe that was what you meant ;)

Comment: Wrong. The order in which the Form's `OnCreate` event is triggered in relation to the C++ class constructor, and the `OnDestroy` event is triggered in relation to the C++ class destructor, is directly related to the Form's `OldCreateOrder` property. When `OldCreateOrder` is true, the `OnCreate` event is triggered BEFORE the C++ constructor, and `OnDestroy` is triggered AFTER the C++ destructor. Both events are triggered by the `TCustomForm` base class. This is the illegal behavior I was referring to - a base class constructor/destructor calling derived class methods in illegal orders.

Comment: This is allowed in Delphi because Delphi uses an object creation model that has an opposite order than C++'s creation model.  Delphi constructs objects in a Derived->Base order, but C++ constructs objects in a Base->Derived order instead. All VCL objects follow the Delphi creation order, even when instantiated in C++ code. They do not follow the C++ creation model. That is how `TCustomForm` can call into the derived Form's `OnCreate/Destroy` events, but that behavior is illegal in C++.

Comment: And this situation is possible in C++ because the `OldCreateOrder` property is quirkly. Even if you set it to false at design-time, it has been known to toggle itself to true at run-time unexpectedly. Thus you can end up accessing data that has not been constructed yet, or has already been freed. This is not speculation. History shows that this has happened many times in the past in real world apps. That is why it is dangerous to use the `OnCreate`/`OnDestroy` events in C++ at all. Avoid them completely and use the C++ constructor/destructor instead.

Comment: And lastly, even [Embarcadero's own documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.OnCreate) says so: "Note: Use of the OnCreate event is discouraged in C++ code because it can interact badly with the form's constructor (see OldCreateOrder). It is recommended that you override the form constructor instead."

Answer (score 2):

`TDictionary` is only for accessing Delphi variables and fields. You can not use and instantiate it in C++ code. Template classes are usable when defined completely in a header file.